# What is the three20 method of passing objects between view controllers?

Tags: iphone, three20

I have a basic RSS Reader I made from three20 tutorials using TTLauncherView as a menu to different feeds and TTTableViewController to show the feed list.

However, I am stuck at the point where from the feed list I click to view the feed item details. I use TTTableImageItem to display my feed items and I'm clueless as to how I am to use the URL variable in said TTTableImageItem to pass objects to the view controller showing the feed item.

I did some searching and I am lead to think that this cannot be done except via TTURLRequest, which leaves me even more confused.

Most of my code is adapted from [IOSGuys](http://iosguy.com/2010/09/06/saving-work-with-three20/) tutorial, which uses a custom data source, data model and parser. I have tried making the data source and data model a singleton but to no avail and I'm unsure if that's even the best way to proceed for something as (presumably) simple as this.

Ideally I intend to pass the entire array of feed items with another argument for the index so that I can make use of UIPageControl to swipe between feeds when I'm at a more in-depth view.

Much help is appreciated! I have been spending too long looming around already!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see also [Three20 : how to pass a class of objects between 2 views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3949208/three20-how-to-pass-a-class-of-objects-between-2-views)

Comment: Managed to do it this way, albeit it has opened up to new issues!

Answer (score 2):

The usual way of doing this is to have some sort of global singleton `Data Manager` class that manages the data models through Core Data, In-Memory Stores or other ways. Each model would have some sort of unique identifier. Doing it this way lends itself to a URL only stack needed to recover your navigation history without having to write state out to file in order to restore. You also can bring up any page in the app at any place with only a single URL. Using a URL scheme only then becomes trivial as you can do something like:

```
yourapp://blogs/jd82kd9
```

and have the blog view controller's `init` method contact the `Data Manager` for the blog with the unique identifier of `jd82kd9`

In your navigator's mappings, you would have something like this:

```
[map from:@"yourapp://blogs/(initWithBlogID:)") toViewController:[MyBlogViewController class]];
```

and then the `initWithBlogID` method would have the signature:

```
- (id)initWithBlogID:(NSString *)blogID;
```